# How is the click scroll amount calculated on a winforms scrollbar?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I click somewhere on the scrollbar that is not the thumb and not the top and bottom arrows, the scrollbar scrolls by a certain amount. given the large change and the min and max values of the scrollbar, how does .Net use these to calculate how much it should scroll when you click on this area.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.largechange(v=VS.71).aspx

> When the user presses the PAGE UP or
>   PAGE DOWN key or clicks in the scroll
>   bar track on either side of the scroll
>   box, the Value property changes
>   according to the value set in the
>   LargeChange property.
>
> You might consider setting the
>   LargeChange value to a percentage of
>   the Height (for a vertically oriented
>   scroll bar) or Width (for a
>   horizontally oriented scroll bar)
>   values. This keeps the distance your
>   scroll bar moves in proportion to its
>   size.